# text file comparision using python matched or not matched?

Tags: python

I have two text files to be compared and output matched or not matched. my program outputs "not matched" even if I try to compare the same text file instead of giving the output as matched.

```
file1 = open('dev1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('dev1.txt', 'r')

num = 0
for line1 in file1:
    for line2 in file2:
        if line1 != line2:
            num += 1

if num >= 1:
    print "not matched"
else:
    print "matched"
```

Comment: Why are you using a nested loop? You should be `zip`ping them together.

Comment: You're comparing every line in file1 with every line in file2 (1_1 -> 2_1, 2_2, 2_3, etc.). Try `all(line1==line2 for (line1, line2) in zip(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines()))`

Comment: the question is to compare two different device config files and output matched or not matched even if small change is noticed (spaces and blanks were discarded).

Answer (score 1):

When comparing two files line by line, you shouldn't use a nested loop. For example,

```
for l1 in f1:
    for l1 in f2:
        ...
```

This means, "for every line in `f1`, compare that line to every line in `f2`", which semantically does not make sense.

What you should instead do is compare *corresponding* lines. The easiest way to do this is using `zip`.

```
for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2):
    ...
```

The means, "compare each line in `f1` to its corresponding line in `f2`", which makes sense.

Next, it seems like all you want to do is see whether any two lines are not equal, and print a message accordingly. In that case, you can cut the comparison short with a `break` statement. Use the `for...else` idiom, so you don't need a flag or a counter.

```
for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2):
    if l1 != l2:
        print('not matched')
        break

else:
    print "matched"
```

The `else` is run only when the loop exits naturally - in other words, when the `break` is not encountered.

If, however, you would like to retrieve a count of all lines that were not equal, you can use `sum` with a generator comprehension -

```
diff = sum(1 for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2) if l1 != l2)
print('not matched' if diff else 'matched')
```

The idea here is that you can do something useful with `diff` after.

Comment: thanks, this worked in some cases!... code did not work if both the text files have same no of lines and same text but in a jumbled way.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGk It didn't work that way because you didn't specify it like that way in the question. Take a look at it again... anyway. please don't edit it now, it'll totally change this question. Open a new one.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGk Wait, actually, change `l1 != l2` to `sorted(l1) != sorted(l2)`. Then it'd work for jumbled letters.